# Gitlab - Cannot: create new project, list team members, add SSH keys or clone / push

Tags: centos, ssh, centos6.4, gitlab

I have just installed Gitlab on my Centos 6.4.

At first glance everything seems to be working fine but for some reason, I have the following issues...:

### Add a new project :

***(Similar issues when adding new SSH keys or listing projects members)***

- *Error:* Can't save project. Please try again later.
- *Log:*

  ```
  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass):
  1: - user = member.user
  2: %li{id: dom_id(user), class: "team_member_row access-#{member.human_access.downcase}"}
  3: .pull-right
  4: - if current_user_can_admin_project
  5: - unless @project.personal? && user == current_user
  ```

---

### Clone or push

- *Error when cloning*:

  ```
  Cloning into 'Vermello'...
   Access denied.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
  ```
- *Asks for git password when pushing.*

---

*Note that I added my SSH key manually using the gitlab-shell script as I couldn't use the interface.*

---

### Sidekiq.log

- I have checked the following link about this issue but it did not solve my problem (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1063#issuecomment-6854410)
- *Log:*

  ```
   ERROR: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
   ERROR: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:119:in `getaddrinfo'
  ```
- */home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml*:

  ```
   # GitLab user. git by default
   user: git

   # Url to gitlab instance. Used for api calls. Should end with a slash.
   gitlab_url: "http://gitlab.vermello-designs.com/"

   ...
  ```

---

### Output of

- `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`:

  ```
  Checking Environment ...

  Git configured for git user? ... yes
  Has python2? ... yes
  python2 is supported version? ... yes

  Checking Environment ... Finished

  Checking GitLab Shell ...

  GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.0 ? ... OK (1.7.0)
  Repo base directory exists? ... yes
  Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
  Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
  Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
  post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
  post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... 
  Vermello / Vermello ... repository is empty

  Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

  Checking Sidekiq ...

  Running? ... yes

  Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

  Checking GitLab ...

  Database config exists? ... yes
  Database is SQLite ... no
  All migrations up? ... yes
  GitLab config exists? ... yes
  GitLab config outdated? ... no
  Log directory writable? ... yes
  Tmp directory writable? ... yes
  Init script exists? ... yes
  Init script up-to-date? ... yes
  Projects have satellites? ... 
  Vermello / Vermello ... can't create, repository is empty
  Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
  Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
  Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.11)

  Checking GitLab ... Finished
  ```

---

### Output of

- `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production`:

  ```
  System information
  System:     CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
  Current User:   git
  Using RVM:  no
  Ruby Version:   1.9.3p0
  Gem Version:    1.8.17
  Bundler Version:1.3.5
  Rake Version:   10.1.0

  GitLab information
  Version:    6.0.0.pre
  Revision:   f602be2
  Directory:  /home/gitlab/gitlabhq
  DB Adapter: mysql2
  URL:        http://gitlab.vermello-designs.com
  HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.vermello-designs.com/some-project.git
  SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.vermello-designs.com:some-project.git
  Using LDAP: no
  Using Omniauth: no

  GitLab Shell
  Version:    1.7.0
  Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
  Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
  Git:        /usr/bin/git
  ```

Thank you for your time, your help is much appreciated!